# Proving continuity in metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, proof-writing, definition

Here is the definition of continuity of a function between metric spaces.

> Let $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$ be two metric spaces. A function $f : X \to Y$ is said to be continuous if for every $ \epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $d_X(x, y) < \delta \implies d_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$

Now in most proofs the writer of the proof omits their calculation of $\delta$ and simply say something along the following lines

> " Let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{c}$, then we have $$d_X(x, y) < \delta \implies ... \implies d_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$$"

(From here on in I'll refer to the above generalized quote as the "seen part of a continuity proof")

But for someone trying to write their own proof this doesn't really give much intuition, to the reader it seems like these $\delta$ are chosen almost magically by the proof writer. This is obviously false as the proof writer has done some algebraic manipulations/rough calculations to see why such a $\delta$ can work.

My question thus is, how (generally) does someone writing up such a proof pick a suitable $\delta$? More explicitly what algebraic manipulations (and by this I mean in the most general sense) are done to arrive at something that shows that proof writer what a suitable choice for $\delta$ would be?

I can think of two procedures.

**1. Start off with $d_Y(f(x), f(y))$ and end up with $d_X(x, y)$ to find suitable choice for $\delta$**

Initially I guessed that to find a suitable choice of $\delta$ one would need to start off with $d_Y(f(x), f(y))$ and do some algebraic manipulations and through some inequalities arrive at $c(d_X(x, y))$ where $c$ is some constant. And from that one could choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{c}$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ we would automatically have $d_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$. The below chain of inequalities shows this procedure from start to finish.

$$d_Y(f(x), f(y)) = ... < ... < c(d_X(x, y)) < c\delta = \epsilon$$

The above is all of the "rough calculations" needed to be done to choose a suitable $\delta$ . Now in the *seen part of my proof* I could write

> "Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{c}$ then we have $$d_X(x, y) < \delta \implies c(d_X(x, y)) < \epsilon \implies d_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$$
>   "

**2. Start off with $d_X(x, y)$ and end up with $d_Y(f(x), f(y))$ to find suitable choice for $\delta$**

I was told that I should start off with $d_X(x, y)$ and end up with $d_Y(f(x), f(y))$ to find suitable choice for $\delta$. In that case one would need to one would need to start off with $d_X(x, y)$ and do some algebraic manipulations and through some inequalities arrive at $c(d_Y(f(x), f(y)))$ where $c$ is some constant. And then from that choose $\delta = c\epsilon$ and then do a bit more work from that to get $d_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$. The below chain of inequalities shows this procedure from start to finish.

$$d_X(x, y) < ... < cd_Y(f(x), f(y)) < c\epsilon$$

which suggests we choose $\delta = c\epsilon$. Then in the seen part of the proof I could write

> "Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and let $\delta = c\epsilon$, then we have $$d_X(x, y) < \delta \implies cd_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \delta \\ \implies cd_Y(f(x), f(y)) < c\epsilon \implies d_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$$

---

In either case I seem to be arriving at the same outcome (correct me if I'm wrong). So my question is what is the difference between those two procedures I outlined above?

Is there any better or more universal way to arrive at a suitable choice for $\delta$? Also is this a one method fit's all kind of thing, i.e. can I do this to prove continuity of any continuous function between metric spaces (I understand that proving some of the inequalities may be very difficult)?

Finally if the first procedure I showed is incorrect, please indicate why it is incorrect (maybe it's the case there that I'm choosing an $\epsilon$ for a specific $\delta$, or maybe the whole chain of inequalities is incorrect, if so please tell me).

---

Also before this is downvoted (either due to length, or something that may seem obvious), note that this is something that many students may be struggling with, as I don't think I've ever come across an explanation that shows how to systematically choose a suitable $\delta$ (because as I've mentioned before nobody writes up their rough calculations in a proof).

Comment: Your definition of continuity is wrong (it's uniform continuity).

Comment: The point is you can take $\delta$ as small as you want, so if some choice fails because current $\delta$ is too big, you can always take smaller one — so ability to pick it small enough without many tries is kind of magic which you learn doing math, I suppose.

Comment: Also, I think that all that e-d istorical gibberish is very unintuitive and misleading (see, you've made a mistake already); continuous functions are going between topological spaces, and if you have a metric space, you can define topology on it as topology generated by open balls, and _then_ prove that function $f$ between metric spaces with that kind of topology is continuous at $x$ if for all e's there are d's s. t. images of it's d-nbhds lie withtin e-nbhds of $f(x)$ — and it's a theorem, not a definition.

Comment: $\delta$ depends on $x$ as well as on $\epsilon$ unless $f$ is uniformly continuous. You can repair your def'n by writing $\delta_x$ for $\delta$.... Beginners in analysis often go through contortions trying to find the largest possible $\delta$ when it is unnecessary. If it holds for $\delta$ it holds for any $\delta'\in (0,\delta)$ so crude upper estimates for a suitable $\delta$  will often simplify things.  For a given $f$ we may find that if $\delta$ exists then it must have certain properties,,, and then we may find that enough of these properties   simultaneously are also sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the complexity of the problem.

Note that $\delta $ is not always proportional to $\epsilon$ and as you mentioned, it is usually the hidden work which makes it hard to understand the proof.

Let us start with an example.

Prove that $$f(x)=x^2+3x-2$$ is continuous at $x=5.$

Suppose $\epsilon>0 $ is given.

We have to choose a $\delta >0 $ such that $$ |x-5| <\delta  \implies |x^2+3x-40|<\epsilon $$

Now we go to our magic corner to find a suitable $\delta $

Note that $$|x^2+3x-40|=|(x-5)(x+8)|$$

We can control $|x-5|$ by our invisible $ \delta$ , so we need to worry about $|x+8|$

We say $x$ is around $5$ so if $\delta <1$ then $$ |x-5|<\delta \implies  4<x<6$$

and as a result $$12 <x+8 <14$$ which implies $$|x+8|<14$$

Now we return to our desk and write, Let $$\delta = min\{1,\frac {\epsilon}{14}\}$$

$$ |x-5|<\delta \implies |x^2+3x-40|= |(x-5)(x+8)|<\delta (14)\le 14(\frac {\epsilon}{14}) =\epsilon $$